# News section snipits

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a news section for a website I'm working on. I'd like to show the first few words of the article then a link to the rest. I'm kicking myself because I remember a few months ago seeing an article on exactly how to do this, but I have no idea where I found it.

I know how to grab the first so many characters from a string but it gets more tracking when you are trying to grab words instead.  If anyone could point me in the direction of a tutorial or article along these things I’d be very grateful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Truncate string on whole words in .Net C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613896/truncate-string-on-whole-words-in-net-c)

Comment: oh Sorry! I did so a search but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to a blog that will return the first X words from a string.

http://dotnetperls.com/first-words

(Please note I haven't written or tested this code)

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably do this with regex.  See example below:

```
private string FindFirstWords (string input, int howManyToFind)
{
      string REGEX = @"([\w]+\s+){" + howManyToFind + "}";
      return Regex.Match(input,REGEX).Value;
}
```

Stolen from http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2005/01/07/348138.aspx